# Oracle Issue (ORA-009111)

Tags: ora-00911

what is the syntax error `(error code-ORA-00911)` in this below code:

```
Insert into ctl_infa_parm
select ‘201405’,
scen_id,
infa_wkf_id,
sess_parm_file_nm,
sess_nm,
parm_nm,
parm_value,
parm_type,
wklt_nm,
actv_flag,
updtd_by,
sysdate,
sysdate
from ctl_infa_parm
where dmth_id=201404;
```

Comment: Do you really have a column called '201405'? (select 201405)

Answer (score 0):

`code-ORA-00911` represents an invalid character (see http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00911_invalid_character.htm). Your `select ‘201405’` is not the same as `select '201405'`. Use `'` instead of `’`.

Comment: Do you get the same error? Because I do not see any other strange character.

Comment: Yeah! Don't know what's the bug :(

Answer (score -2):

It's the semi colon at the end. You have to remove it.

Comment: Why? Semi-colons are part of SQL and some databases expect them.